# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /PHOP.php on line 19

Tags: php

```
class Config
{
   const Caching = true;
   const Logging = false;
   const LogFile = 'log.txt';

   const PublicUrl = 'http://vptelevision.com/op';

   static $RemotePaths = [
      "http://awcommunity.org/romperroom",
      "http://aw.platform3d.com/multipath"
   ];

   static $AssetDirectories = [
      "models",
      "textures",
      "avatars",
      "sounds",
      "seqs",
   ];

   static $Plugins = [
      "prim",
   ];
}
```

I am using Netbeans and its not catching this at all. I am having a hard time figuring out what is wrong with this piece of code

Comment: Which line is line 19?

Comment: Which version are you using

Answer (score 3):

Your version of PHP does not support [short array syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php). Consider upgrading to PHP 5.4+, or use `array()` instead of `[]`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are developing arrays in PHP 5.4+ you might need to do it as bellow:

```
static $RemotePaths = array(
      "http://awcommunity.org/romperroom",
      "http://aw.platform3d.com/multipath"
);
```

Basically, in PHP an array takes any number of comma-separated as arguments.

```
array(
    key  => value,
    key2 => value2,
    key3 => value3,
    ...
)
```

In case of no key declaration for the array values, they are assigned to values starting from 0 incremented by one.

and the array here is identical to :

```
static $RemotePaths = array(
  [0] => "http://awcommunity.org/romperroom",
  [1] => "http://aw.platform3d.com/multipath"
);
```

Comment: Explaining *why* this works is rather important; the questioner obviously did not know when they posed the question.

Answer (score 0):

Short-style arrays where only introducted in php 5.4. You are running your code with something older than that. Switch back to the long style array initializers:

```
class Config
{
   const Caching = true;
   const Logging = false;
   const LogFile = 'log.txt';

   const PublicUrl = 'http://vptelevision.com/op';

   static $RemotePaths = array(
      "http://awcommunity.org/romperroom",
      "http://aw.platform3d.com/multipath"
   );

   static $AssetDirectories = array(
      "models",
      "textures",
      "avatars",
      "sounds",
      "seqs",
   );

   static $Plugins = array(
      "prim",
   );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your version does not support the short-style array. Use the array by using the array() function like this

```
 static $AssetDirectories = array(
      "models",
      "textures",
      "avatars",
      "sounds",
      "seqs"
   );
```

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

you must be running your application on `PHP5.4` or above to use short array syntax, either upgrade to PHP5.4 or change your code to

```
class Config
{
   const Caching = true;
   const Logging = false;
   const LogFile = 'log.txt';

   const PublicUrl = 'http://vptelevision.com/op';

   static $RemotePaths = array(
      "http://awcommunity.org/romperroom",
      "http://aw.platform3d.com/multipath"
   );

   static $AssetDirectories = array(
      "models",
      "textures",
      "avatars",
      "sounds",
      "seqs",
   );

   static $Plugins = array(
      "prim",
   );
}
```